# Regular Expression for testing length of string part

Tags: regex

Hi I need a regular expression which is accepting the following strings:

```
[A-Z]-[A-Z]{3-5}[0-9]{2-4}
```

for example *X-ABC123* or *Y-AB1234*

The problem now is that the total length of the string on the right side of the hyphen must always be 5 chars in length. Is there a chance to check that with regular expressions only?

Comment: @PrinceJohnWesley I deleted my comment but thanks anyway :D

Comment: your selection rule and your example don't match, both of your examples have 6 chars after the - and the number of letters and digests you require can only be 5 if there is 3 and 2, may be you should be a bit more specific about what you need so one of the great answers you have gotten can be tailored more for your need

Answer (score 1):

Just add this after the hyphen :

```
/(?=[A-Z\d]{5}$)/
```

Resulting in :

```
/^[A-Z]-(?=[A-Z\d]{5}$)[A-Z]{3,5}[0-9]{2,4}/
```

This assumes that your input strings are the strings you posted.

```
X-ABC123 -> fails
Y-AB1234 -> fails
A-ABD12  -> matches
A-ABV111 -> fails
```

If the string is part of another string you can replace the $ anchor with \s|$ for example.

Comment: why `(?=[A-Z\d]{0,5}$)` instead of `(?=[A-Z\d]{5,5}$)`?

Comment: @FailedDev or replace the `$` anchor by `\b` a word boundary

Comment: Why `{0,5}` when just `{5}` is correct: *must always be 5 chars in length* (not up to 5)

Comment: @PrinceJohnWesley Only `{5}` is enough, `{5,5}` is not needed

Comment: @PrinceJohnWesley +0.5 see updated answer. :D. Not {5,5} rather {5}.

Comment: Since both of the examples have six characters after the hyphen, I wonder if the OP doesn't really mean *at least* five, which would be `{5,}`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's definitely possible, from a language theory point of view. Just group it and add the constraint :

I just need to know which language is specifying the regex but something like this :

```
[A-Z]-(^[A-Z][A-Z0-9]4)
```

I had the feeling you wanted the right part to start with one char for sure, then either chars or numbers

Comment: That doesn't look like any regex flavor I'm familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

First the problems in your regex

The quantifier is `{3,5}` and not `{3-5}` (this would match literally "{3-5}")

You want 3 to 5 letters and 2 to 4 digits and in total 5 letters and digits ==> the only valid combination is then 3 letters followed by 2 digits.

In general you can use a positive lookahead for this

```
^[A-Z]-(?=.{5}$)[A-Z]{3,5}[0-9]{2,4}$
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2v57m)

The `(?=.{5}$)` part is just looking, if there are from its position to the end (`$`) 5 characters.

But as said before, if the 3-5 and 2-4 and overall 5 is valid you can just do

```
^[A-Z]-[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{2}$
```

Comment: minor improvement. Since you are using the lookahead you might as well fail it there if the characters matching are not [A-Z\d] instead of ".".

Comment: @FailedDev for the lookahead its just fine to use `.` for a length check. The wanted characters are then matched by the following pattern.

Comment: Yes but you lose efficiency. A-@#$#@ matches in the lookahead but then fails. You could have failed it before the actual capture.

Comment: @FailedDev: I think you're getting a little carried away, there. :-)

Comment: @AlanMoore Hm. Maybe I am but wouldn't then lookahead have to evaluate first before whatever comes next? What I mean is, wouldn't the overall regex fail at the moment the lookahead fails?

Comment: @FailedDev:  My point is that it doesn't matter; it's premature optimization in this case.  Save it for the really complex problems, or for questions that are specifically about poorly performing regexes.